# Why does std::stack use std::deque by default?

Tags: c++, stl, containers

Since the only operations required for a container to be used in a stack are:

- back()
- push_back()
- pop_back()

Why is the default container for it a deque instead of a vector?

Don't deque reallocations give a buffer of elements before front() so that push_front() is an efficient operation? Aren't these elements wasted since they will never ever be used in the context of a stack?

If there is no overhead for using a deque this way instead of a vector, why is the default for priority_queue a vector not a deque also? (priority_queue requires front(), push_back(), and pop_back() - essentially the same as for stack)

---

**Updated based on the Answers below:**

It appears that the way deque is usually implemented is a variable size array of fixed size arrays. This makes growing faster than a vector (which requires reallocation and copying), so for something like a stack which is all about adding and removing elements, deque is likely a better choice.

priority_queue requires indexing heavily, as every removal and insertion requires you to run pop_heap() or push_heap(). This probably makes vector a better choice there since adding an element is still amortized constant anyways.

Comment: The reasoning in your 'update' isn't quite right.  vector normally adds and removes elements from the end _faster_ than a deque.  deque is faster for _growing memory_, not pushing elements.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

As the container grows, a reallocation for a vector requires copying all the elements into the new block of memory.  Growing a deque allocates a new block and links it to the list of blocks - no copies are required.

Of course you can specify that a different backing container be used if you like.  So if you have a stack that you know is not going to grow much, tell it to use a vector instead of a deque if that's your preference.

Comment: But when the list of pointers to blocks grows, this list must occasionally be reallocated just like a vector must; asymptotically, any gain in efficiency is by a constant factor at best. And iterator manipulation needed to do push and pop correctly is much more complicated for `std::deque` than it is for `std::vector`, and these operations are likely to be used much more frequently than reallocations. I have a hard time believing that `std::deque` would ever beat `std::vector` in practice.

Comment: @Michael Burr: Then why not use `list`, why `deque`?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen regarding you say you have a hard time believing ... could you please make a clear standpoint? do you mean you're now believing `std::deque` does have a chance to beat `std::vector` in practice, or do you mean you still doubt it? thanks.

Comment: @fleix I don't see why it is so important whether I personally have an easier time believing that `std::deque` will do as well as `std::vector` in practical applications. But for what its worth, my personal experience is that I need stack and queue data structures not for one large and complexity-crucial task, but for many small occasions sprinkled through my code. As such I care more about behaviour in the small than in the large; and deque shines particularly dull there. My preference is to use neither, but (self-implemented) singly linked lists instead. But you mileage may vary.

Answer (score 13):

See Herb Sutter's [Guru of the Week 54](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/054.htm) for the relative merits of vector and deque where either would do.

I imagine the inconsistency between priority_queue and queue is simply that different people implemented them.

Comment: priority_queue doesn't actually use push/pop_front, and references to elements besides the first are invalidated by the heap operations. So, none of the benefits of deque would apply, unlike the case of a regular queue.

Comment: Also, `priority_queue` must remain sorted, so the higher overhead of randomly accessing `deque::iterator` is more problematic.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: `priority_queue` has a "magic order" that's maintained, it's not sorted.  However, your point stands.