# c++ deque vs queue vs stack

Tags: c++, containers

Queue and Stack are a structures widely mentioned. However, in C++, for queue you can do it in two ways:

```
#include <queue>
#include <deque>
```

but for stack you can only do it like this

```
#include <stack>
```

My question is, what's the difference between queue and deque, why two structures proposed? For stack, any other structure could be included?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Moron/Aryabhatta is correct, but a little more detail may be helpful.

Queue and stack are higher level containers than deque, vector, or list. By this, I mean that you can build a queue or stack out of the lower level containers.

For example:

```
  std::stack<int, std::deque<int> > s;
  std::queue<double, std::list<double> > q;
```

Will build a stack of ints using a deque as the underlying container and a queue of doubles using a list as the underlying container.

You can think of `s` as a restricted deque and `q` as a restricted list.

All that is necessary is that the lower level container implements the methods needed by the higher level container. These are `back()`, `push_back()`, and `pop_back()` for stack and `front()`, `back()`, `push_back()`, and `pop_front()` for queue.

See [stack](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) and [queue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) for more detail.

With respect to the deque, it is much more than a queue where you can insert at both ends. In particular, it has the random access `operator[]`. This makes it more like a vector, but a vector where you can insert and delete at the beginning with `push_front()` and `pop_front()`.

See [deque](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) for detail.

Comment: `stack` and `queue` ___just restrict___ `deque` from its full featureset.

Answer (score 82):

`Queue`: you can insert only in one end and remove from the other.

`Deque`: you can insert and remove from both ends.

So using a `Deque`, you can model a `Queue` as well as a `Stack`.

Hint:
`Deque` is short for "**D**ouble **e**nded **que**ue".

Comment: will it not overkill if you use a Deque to model a stack?

Comment: You can't model a stack with a queue.

Comment: There are a lot more differences. `queue` does not satisfy the requirements of a container. It has no iterators, for heaven's sake!

Comment: @skydoor Of all the standard library containers, the deque is arguably the one with the lowest overhead.

Comment: "will it not overkill if you use a Deque to model a stack?"  - Possibly, but as these are templates only the code you use will get put into your executable/library,

Comment: @skydoor: Just as an FYI, the STL's `std::stack` uses a `std::deque` as the backing container by default. I speculate on the reason here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102459/why-does-stdstack-use-stddeque-by-default/102529#102529 (basically that growing a `deque` is low overhead).

Answer (score 38):

`deque` is a container template. It satisfies the requirements for a sequence with random-access iterators, much like a `vector`.

`queue` is not a container at all, it is an *adaptor*. It contains a container and provides a different, more specific interface. Use `queue` when you want to remember (or remind) to avoid operations besides `push[_back]` and `pop[_front]`, `front` and `back`, `size` and `empty`. You can't look at elements inside the `queue` besides the first and last, at all!

Comment: Adaptor -- in other words _unnecessary functionality crippler_, but adaptor is just fine

Answer (score 25):

In the C++ library, both `std::stack` and `std::queue` are implemented as container *adapters*. That means they provide the interface of a stack or a queue respectively, but neither is really a container in itself. Instead, they use some other container (e.g. `std::deque` or `std::list` to actually store the data), and the `std::stack` class just has a tiny bit of code to translate `push` and `pop` to `push_back` and `pop_back` (and `std::queue` does roughly the same, but using `push_back` and `pop_front`).

Comment: For a `queue`, VS also seems to map `pop` to `pop_front`, and `push` to `push_back`, so I guess this is implementation dependent.

Comment: @chappjc: Nope--re-checking, just my memory was off. `pop_front` and `push_back` are what's required. My apologies.

Answer (score 8):

A deque is a double-ended queue, which allows easy insertion/removal from either end.  Queues only allow insertion in one end and retrieval from the other.

Answer (score 5):

deque supports insert/pop from back & front

queue only supports insert to the back, and pop from the front. You know, a FIFO (first in first out).

Answer (score 0):

A deque is double-ended. A queue isn't.

Comment: Explain the implementation of stack like how it is added in queue and double ended queue(deque).

Answer (score 0):

> Priority queue dequeue happens according to some ordering (priority) comparison not the enqueue order.
>
> For instance you might store timed events in one where you want to pull out the soonest event first and query for its scheduled time so you can sleep until that point in time.
>
> Priority queues are often implemented using heaps.

by Mike Anderson here:
https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-a-priority-queue-and-a-queue

Answer (score 0):

In deque(double-ended queue) The element can be inserted from the back and removed from the rear(like in stack), but queue only allows removal from the front.

Comment: This answer doesn't add anything new to the topic (and most of answers are from 2010)