# When to prefer stack/queue over deque?

Tags: c++, stack, queue, deque, container-classes

I know that stack/queue is container adaptor that use deque as its default underlying container. But why the hassle when we can just use deque as a stack or a queue? And I don't see the situations where we have to use stack/queue with different underlying containers other than deque either. Besides, does a stack/queue (with underlying deque) cost a bit more memory than a deque? (the data structure is more complex so it has to do, right?). If so, then is the difference big if the data is huge?

**Edit:** Why was this question marked as duplicate and was linked to
[c++ deque vs queue vs stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247982/deque-vs-queue-in-c?lq=1) ? I didn't ask the difference between deque and queue (as I've already known). I asked why not use a deque as a stack/queue instead of using the class stack/queue, and some other questions regarding memory consumption.

Answer (score 4):

If you need a stack or a queue, then **use the correct container**.  They are designed to prevent certain operations that would be allowable on a `deque`, such as adding or removing an element in the middle, or even iterating through the container.  Such operations are totally unacceptable in a strict stack or queue implementation.

**You might think it's fine** to use a `deque` because *you* know that you intended to use it as a normal queue.  But when somebody else comes along a few years later and your project has grown significantly, **it might not be at all obvious to that person**.  Doing a non-queue operation *just because they can* to hack around some other issue, your program may inadvertently be broken in subtle ways that could go undetected for weeks, months or years.

Answer (score 2):

The container adaptors are there for their **interface**. Yes, you can use `std::deque` directly instead, but you don't worry about the underlying container for the most part, rather you have a interface (behavior) for a stack/queue. The adaptors *adapt* a container to give you a certain behavior and it makes it easier to think in terms of the data structure (i.e. stack or queue). For a `stack` or `queue` container adaptor, the interface is a **restricted subset** of what the underlying container provides, this also may prevent errors or using the container in way that wasn't intended.