# Why are these constructors of std::stack explicit

Tags: c++, c++11, stack

I have questions about `std::stack` Why  these two constructors are `explicit` ?

```
     explicit stack( const Container& cont = Container() );
     explicit stack( Container&& cont = Container() );
```

**Note:** [Source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack)

Comment: I don't get your 3. (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/operator%3D)?

Comment: One question per question, please.

Comment: (1): [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102459/why-does-stdstack-use-stddeque-by-default?rq=1)

Comment: Why don't you just ask question 2 so we do not have to close this as a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102459/why-does-stdstack-use-stddeque-by-default?rq=1

Comment: I edited the post ... didnt see operator=

Comment: So they don't get invoked implicitly, of course.

Comment: You wouldn't want a function expecting a `const std::stack&` to accept an `std::vector` and create a temporary copy every time. The `explicit` is there to warn the caller that they should probably handle the conversion, either with an explicit cast or by creating an `std::stack`

Comment: @Hurkyl surely the more interesting interpretation of the question is "why should implicit construction from these constructors be avoided".

Answer (score 4):

The constructors are explicit so you can't accidentally pass an underlying container (such as `vector` or `deque`) to a function expecting a `stack`, resulting in unexpected copying (not to mention violating the principle of least surprise).

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that if you assume implicit invocation, what would happen if others followed your example?  So for instance the following fails to compile

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Test {
  public:

    Test(const std::vector<int>&) {
        cout << "Test(const std::Vector<int>&)" << endl;
    }
};
class AnotherTest {
  public:

    AnotherTest(const std::vector<int>&) {
        cout << "AnotherTest(const std::Vector<int>&)" << endl;
    }
};

void test_function(const AnotherTest&) {
    cout << "fucntion(const AnotherTest&)" << endl;
}
void test_function(const Test&) {
    cout << "fucntion(const Test&)" << endl;
}

int main() {
    const std::vector<int> vec {1, 2, 3};
    test_function(vec);

    return 0;
}
```

You can easily see this problem occurring with a `stack` and a `queue`.