# Is there any complexity difference between a std::vector used as a stack and a std::stack?

Tags: c++, std

Like the title asks Is there any time or space difference between a std::vector used as a stack and a std::stack ?

Comment: std::stack is a container adapter that can be based on std::vector. So in fact there is no difference.

Answer (score 4):

A `std::stack` wraps another container. If the backing container of your stack is a `std::vector`, then no, there is no difference.

The default backing container is however a `std::deque`, which can have different storage and timing behaviour

See [std::stack](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/) for details

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no difference in complexity. `std::vector` is a Container. `std::stack` is an Adaptor of a container.

By default `std::stack` uses `std::deque` as the container it "adapts". But its actually a *class-template* that allows you to pass in the type of the  underlying container you want it to use.

---

You can equally use a `std::vector` as the underlying container:

```
template<typename T>
using MyVectorStack = std::stack<T, std::vector<T>>;
```

---

---

**However,**

In the case of `std::stack`, the difference between using `std::deque` vs `std::vector` as the underlying container is primarily its memory allocation strategies.

When popping from a `std::vector`, there's no chance that memory will be returned to the memory allocator unless if the vector is empty. When popping from a `std::deque`, memory may be returned to the memory allocator if the "pop" frees a deque block.

See [Why does std::stack use std::deque by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102459/why-does-stdstack-use-stddeque-by-default)