# Why is sizeof(std::stack<int>) so large?

Tags: c++, gcc

In gcc I measured `sizeof(std::stack<int>)` and it show 80 bytes. Why it is so large?

It can contain pointer to the top and the size. Even if it contain also the pointer to the allocator, it should be not more than 20 bytes.

Another example, `sizeof(std::set<int>)` is 48 bytes.

Comment: Yes that does seem a bit fat (on a cursory glance), for both containers. Yes you are correct about the size pretty much having to be a member - as asking for the size needs to be O(1) from C++11. What does your implementation have as data members?

Comment: `stack` is only containter adapter. By default, `std::deque` is stored inside adapter. It is rather hard to implement deque by pointer and the size variable.

Comment: By default (it is possible to change) a `std::stack` contains a `std::deque` which has elements that are not contiguous, requirements on complexity of some operations, etc etc.   That set of properties requires a number of elements of book-keeping (e.g. at least a pair of iterators, storing the size separately, etc) that will be represented in the size of a `std::deque`.

Answer (score 8):

You know you can read [the source](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_stack.h) yourself, right?

`class stack` has a [single member](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_stack.h#L146-L148), a `_Sequence` which is a type alias for `std::deque<_Tp>` (and `_Tp` is `int`).

Off to the [implementation of `std::deque`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_deque.h): that is just a [wrapper](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_deque.h#L787) around `_Deque_base`, which is a [wrapper](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_deque.h#L612) around `_Deque_impl`. That *in turn* holds a `_Deque_impl_data`, and finally we arrive at [the following](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_deque.h#L612):

```
struct _Deque_impl_data {
    _Map_pointer _M_map;
    size_t _M_map_size;
    iterator _M_start;
    iterator _M_finish;
...
};
```

where `iterator` is a `_Deque_iterator` with the [following members](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_deque.h#L142-L145):

```
struct _Deque_iterator {
...
      _Elt_pointer _M_cur;
      _Elt_pointer _M_first;
      _Elt_pointer _M_last;
      _Map_pointer _M_node;
...
}
```

Summing it all up: each iterator holds 4 pointers (=32 bytes in a 64-bit system), and then `_Deque_impl_data` holds another two pointers, for a total of 80 bytes.

Comment: But why is this implemented using std::deque (double-ended queue)? It doesn't need such functionality. It does not contain an iterator, it can be inserted or removed only from the top.

Comment: There's an [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102459/why-does-stdstack-use-stddeque-by-default) about that

Comment: No, that doesn't answer my question. My question is, why does it use a double-ended queue, but not a one-ended queue/list/or something like that and without any iterator item? It's excessive and now it weights 80 bytes.

The implementation of such plain stack is very simple. From the very weighted standard stack, I need include additional non-standard library.